# How can i make for loop a recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, recursion

How can I make this code a recursive method?

```
for (int i = 3; i < arr.length; i++) {
    writer.write(arr[i] + "\n");
    strout += arr[i] + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to make that recursive?

Comment: i have only one for loop in my code and professor wants a recursive function

Comment: i was finally able to get the recursive function to work in my code. there were a few things I had to change in order to make it happen. this is what i did to call the function.           String strRec = printRecursive(writer,arr,3);
                     writer.write(strRec);
                     strout +=strRec;

Answer (score 2):

You can try encapsulating the code in a function:

```
 public static String printRecursive(BufferedWriter writer, String[] arr, int i) throws IOException {        
     String strout = "";
     if(i<arr.length) {
        writer.write(arr[i] + "\n");
        //System.out.println(arr[i] + "\n");
        strout += arr[i] + "\n" + printRecursive(writer,arr,i+1);
     }
    return strout;
 }
```

And you can call it from main:

```
  String strRec = printRecursive(writer,arr,3);
```

I hope this help you.

Edited: Added writer according last comment

Comment: when i add the above code block i get error. to create a class for writer.

Comment: I will try to help you, but I don't know how you have defined your writer because in your question I can't see this. Of course, you should declare inside the function if it isn't a general variable of the class. Also you can uncomment the System.out.println I wrote.

Comment: try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(symbol + ".csv")))
                {  
                    writer.write("Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume\n");
                                 
                    for (int i = 3; i < arr.length; i++)
                    {
                        writer.write(arr[i] + "\n");
                        strout += arr[i] + "\n";
                    }

Comment: I've edited the answer above, you can add the writer as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
let arr = [/* array elements */];
let idx = 3;
let stdout = "";

const recursiveMethod = () => {
  writer.write(`${arr[idx]}\n`);
  strout += `${arr[idx]}\n`;
  
  if(idx < arr.length) {
    idx++;
    return recursiveMethod();
  }
}

recursiveMethod();
```